# WooCommerce add_to_cart

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I'm creating a WooCommerce product programmatically ([Create product via CRUD](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52941994/537566)) and wants to add it to its cart.

Code I'm using is marked as legacy ([WC_Cart](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WC_Cart.html))

```
$cart = new WC_Cart();
$cart->add_to_cart($product_id);
```

**The question:** Is there a newer way to add product(s) to the cart?

Comment: You can use `WC()->cart->add_to_cart()`.

Comment: @SallyCJ Thank you. I can't seem to find any documentation of the WC class on https://docs.woocommerce.com/

Comment: You can find it [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WooCommerce.html) for the main WooCommerce class. `WC()` is a wrapper function for the instance of that class, and `WC()->cart` is the `WC_Cart` instance, so there's no need to `new WC_Cart()`. And there's a snippet [here](https://docs.woocommerce.com/document/automatically-add-product-to-cart-on-visit/) which might be helpful to you. :)

Comment: @SallyCJ please make this an answer ;-)

Comment: I posted an answer. I hope that it will be helpful to you and other folks. ;) (sorry for the delay, my laptop was misbehaving)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **The question:** Is there a newer way to add product(s) to the cart?

Well, `WC_Cart::add_to_cart()` is still the way to do it.

Except (on the front-end), there's no need to reinstantiate the cart class:

```
$cart = new WC_Cart();
```

because the [main WooCommerce class](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/class-WooCommerce.html) already [instantiates `WC_Cart`](https://docs.woocommerce.com/wc-apidocs/source-class-WooCommerce.html#476), and you can easily access the class instance like so:

```
$cart = wc()->cart;
//$cart = WC()->cart; // same as above, but wc() (i.e. lowercase) is actually preferred :)
```

where `wc()` is a wrapper function that returns the main instance of the main WooCommerce class.

And to add a product into the cart, you can use either of these options:

```
// Option #1
wc()->cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );

// Option #2: Here we assign wc()->cart to a variable.
$cart = wc()->cart;
$cart->add_to_cart( $product_id );
```

Hope that helps! :)